# Design pattern for import and update actions

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

I have a small component required for an application.  The component that loads a csv file and then updates customer records based on the data it finds.  There will be a single csv file for every customer update.

1. Checks a file location for csv files
2. For each csv file it finds, load the csv file, parse it and update the customer data with any updated data

Thats it.

However im torn between a couple of ways to do this.

1. Have a single Updater() class which does everything.
2. Have an Update() class which is a representation of the loaded csv data, this knows how to parse the csv etc.  and then also have an Updater() class that is responsible for updating the customer records.  The Update() class would have an Updater()

Which of these is the correct solution or are there any other better solutions to this?

Comment: I think you need a few more intermediate classes between your `update` class and whatever it is that you're updating`

Comment: This module of your app will change in the future? How often do you need to run this update task? Where the client data is stored? Your csv file is simple to parse, or contains garbage? A good design depends on all of this i guess!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are thinking of a real general design, consider the following:

- Class `UpdateSet`:  A list of updates.  A CSV file if you want.
- Interface `UpdateInstance`:  The different types of updates, from a request point of view.  A CSV line if you want.
- Class `InsertInstance`: Implements `UpdateInstance`.  An insert request.
- Class `DeleteInstance`: Implements `UpdateInstance`.  A delete request.
- Class `ChangeInstance`: Implements `UpdateInstance`.  An update request.
- Interface `UpdateSetBuilder`:  Produces an `UpdateSet` from somewhere.
- Class `CSVUpdateSetBuilder`:  Implements `UpdateSetBuilder` by reading a CSV file.  Probably a singleton object.
- Interface `UpdateParser`:  Takes a CSV line and produces an `UpdateInstance` (or refuses it).
- Class `InsertParser`: Implements `UpdateParser`.  Probably a singleton object.  Detects and parses an insert request.
- Class `DeleteParser`: Implements `UpdateParser`.  Probably a singleton object.  Detects and parses a delete request.
- Class `ChangeParser`: Implements `UpdateParser`.  Probably a singleton object.  Detects and parses an update request.

The different `UpdateParser`s are registered with the `CSVUpdateSetBuilder` and selected through a delegation mechanism (i.e. each of them is given in turn the opportunity of recognizing a record, if it returns null, the next `UpdateParser` will be given its chance).

- Class `Updater`:  Takes a collection of `CustomerRecords` and applies an `UpdateSet` to it.
- Interface `UpdateTypeDoer`: The different types of operations, from an execution point of view.
- Class `InsertDoer`: Implements `UpdateTypeDoer`.  Detects `InsertInstance` objects and applies them to the data.
- Class `DeleteDoer`: Implements `UpdateTypeDoer`.  Detects `DeleteInstance` objects and applies a delete request to the data.
- Class `ChangeDoer`: Implements `UpdateTypeDoer`.  Detects `ChangeInstance` objects and applies an update request to the data.

The different `UpdateTypeDoer`s are registered with the `Updater` and selected through a delegation mechanism (i.e. each of them is given in turn the opportunity of recognizing a record, if it returns null, the next `UpdateTypeDoer` will be given the opportunity).

Advantages:  Very flexible, and easy to evolve and modify (add new data sources, update types, etc).
Disadvantages:  A big investment in terms of design and implementation time that maybe never pays back.  Are you ever going to add types of update?  Different data sources?  File formats?

I've always thought that in design and programming there are 2 things you can do endlessly:  abstraction and indirection.  Knowing how much is too little and how much is too much is the real art.

Answer (score 0):

Split the functionality. It's difficult to say without knowing more about the code, but I'd say at least have the loading/parsing of the CSV separate from applying it to your internal record. I'd probably keep the code that searches the directory for CSVs separate from both of them.

Answer (score 0):

I would keep it as simple as possible (1 class) for now unless you need to add more functionality.  Will other classes need to get updates?  If not, don't bother designing, creating (and testing) a more complication system.

If however you need multiple classes, perhaps the Observer Pattern is what you are looking for.  That way other objects register that they want to get update events and your class that knows how to parse these records fires Update events.  The Listening class can receive those Update events and does the actual update.

Comment: I will agree with this if Marty can keep the whole thing to 1000 lines or fewer, including reasonable javadoc. Note that this way makes unit testing harder, but if it's as simple as you think then that shouldn't be a huge deal.

Comment: nobody ever needs to make any system more complicated. What people need is additional functionality.

Comment: good point @khachik, I misspoke; I've updated my post. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If the logic
`that loads a csv file` and the logic that `then updates customer records based on the data it finds` are both pretty simple/short then keep them in a single `Updater` class that first loads the data and then updates it.

If the CSV data itself is complex it might be better to make an additional class that stores the data of each object (entry in the csv file) with the appropriate mutators(setters/getters). It can still be used in a single class that reads the file, creates an object for each entry and then updates the customer records.

The only reason I could think of to split the `Updater` in 2 separate classes is having very complex logic of reading the file and updating the customer records. But I can't see how they could be so hard/long to implement.